# Group by Columns, and concatenate 1 column, and do the Sum for 1 Column for List

Tags: c#, linq, linq-group

I need to Group by Columns, and concatenate 1 column, and do the Sum for 1 Column.

1. Group by : 1st by Vendor then by Type
2. Concatenate by: Month
3. Sum by :NumberInvoice

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var InputData = new List<Invoice>()
            {
                new Invoice{ Vendor = "Microsoft", NumberInvoice= 10, Type= "PC", Month = "1" },
                new Invoice{ Vendor = "Microsoft", NumberInvoice= 10, Type= "PC", Month = "2" },
                new Invoice{ Vendor = "Microsoft", NumberInvoice= 10, Type= "Surface", Month = "1" },
                new Invoice{ Vendor = "Microsoft", NumberInvoice= 20, Type= "PC", Month = "1" },
                new Invoice{ Vendor = "Microsoft", NumberInvoice= 20, Type= "PC", Month = "2" },
                new Invoice{ Vendor = "Microsoft", NumberInvoice= 30, Type= "Surface", Month = "1" },
                new Invoice{ Vendor = "IBM", NumberInvoice= 50, Type= "Network", Month = "5" },
                new Invoice{ Vendor = "IBM", NumberInvoice= 60, Type= "Graphic Card", Month = "6" }
            };

            var result = (InputData.AsEnumerable() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()).Select(
                    x => new
                    {
                        x.Vendor,
                        x.NumberInvoice,
                        x.Type,
                        x.Month
                    }
                ).GroupBy(
                    y => new
                    {
                        y.Vendor,
                        y.NumberInvoice,
                        y.Type,
                        y.Month
                    }
                )
                .Select(
                    a => new Invoice
                    {
                        Vendor = a.Key.Vendor,
                        NumberInvoice = a.Key.NumberInvoice,
                        Type = a.Key.Type,
                        Month = a.Key.Month,
                    }
                    ).ToList();
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Vendor+" "+ item.NumberInvoice + " " + item.Type + " " + item.Month);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public class Invoice
        {
            public string Vendor { get; set; }
            public decimal NumberInvoice { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public string Month { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the output

```
Microsoft 10 PC 1
Microsoft 10 PC 2
Microsoft 10 Surface 1
Microsoft 20 PC 1
Microsoft 20 PC 2
Microsoft 30 Surface 1
IBM 50 Network 5
IBM 60 Graphic Card 6
```

The desired output should be like this:

```
Vendor       Type         Month    NumberInvoice
-------------------------------------------------
Microsoft    PC           1,2      60      
Microsoft    Surface      1        40   
IBM          Network      5        50     
IBM          Graphic Card 6        60
```

As you see For Microsoft, Month 1 and 2 concatenated, and do the Sum for NumberInvoice.
So I can accomplish this output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should group by `Vendor` and `Type`only.
2. Perform `.Sum()` for `NumberInvoice`. And for `Months`, `.Select()` and `.Distinct()` to add the distinct months to the list.
3. Returns the result as `List<GroupedInvoice>`. (Create another class to hold the `Months` as a `string` list/array.
4. (Optional) The first `.Select()` to me is unnecessary, would suggest being removed.

```cs
var result = (InputData.AsEnumerable() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException())
    .GroupBy(
        y => new
        {
            y.Vendor,
            y.Type
        }
    )
    .Select(
        a => new GroupedInvoice
        {
            Vendor = a.Key.Vendor,
            Type = a.Key.Type,
            NumberInvoice = a.Sum(x => x.NumberInvoice),
            Month = a.Select(x => x.Month).Distinct().ToArray(),
        }
    ).ToList();
```

```cs
public class GroupedInvoice
{
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
    public decimal NumberInvoice { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string[] Months { get; set; }
}
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FvuPJp)

Comment: you are right, the 1st select is not needed, this is the perfect solution for me,  I totally forget about creating another class, thnx